# Update postgres database properties in activiti source code

Tags: java, database, postgresql, activiti

I have downloaded the latest activiti source code(5.21.0),by default the activiti will point to h2 database and I want to change that to postgres.I made changes in db.properties file in-order to point my database.When I restart the activiti-explorer still it's pointing to h2 db. I have added the dependency of postgres in activiti POM file as well. My db.properties file is as follow:

```
    db=postgres
    jdbc.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
    jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/activitiDB
    jdbc.username=postgres
    jdbc.password=password
```

Can anyone help me to sort it out.

Answer (score 1):

Sagari , did you try modifying the activiti engine as well. There is a configuration file for the same which contains the datasource properties. This can be used as the alternative to the property file approach.

It is elaborated here :

http://www.activiti.org/userguide/
(Database configuration)

Also could you try mvn clean and try running again. May be it will help

Answer (score 1):

How are you running Explorer? Did you do a build of the webapp to get the war.
If so, changing the db.properties is all that's needed indeed. Where did you put that file?

Also, there's no need to clone the source code, you can download the latest zip file from http://activiti.org/download.html, it contains the explorer war file already.